# Excel: How to merge coma separated list of keywords from different cells dynamically into one single cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, libreoffice-calc

I have following table with keywords:

```
---------------------------------------
|group   | keywords                   |
---------------------------------------
|1       | lorem, ipsum, aeque, dolor |
---------------------------------------
|2       | ipsum, oratio, vim, lorem  |
---------------------------------------
|3       | lorem, qualisque, dolor    |
---------------------------------------
```

And I want to get a summery with all keywords merged into one cell with an excel function:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
|summary | aeque, dolor, ipsum, lorem, oratio, qualisque, vim |
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

The user should be able to edit the keywords in the first table and the summary should be rebuild automatically.

I could use CONCATENATE to join all the keywords, but how do I get an ordered string with unique keywords from this concatenated string?

Comment: Do you want a VBA solution, or formula?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Anything that works is welcome, i guess formula would be more easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With data in column **A** like:

[image]

the following User Define Function *(UDF)*:

```
Public Function KonKat(rIN As Range) As String
    Dim r As Range, c As Collection
    Set c = New Collection

    For Each r In rIN
        ary = Split(Replace(r.Value, " ", ""), ",")
        On Error Resume Next
        For Each a In ary
            c.Add a, CStr(a)
            If Err.Number = 0 Then
                KonKat = KonKat & ", " & a
            Else
                Err.Number = 0
            End If
        Next a
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next r
    KonKat = Mid(KonKat, 3)
End Function
```

will do the concatenation and remove the duplicates:

[image]

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

```
=konkat(A1:Z1)
```

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**